# How to use a TRIM function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I cannot get this TRIM code to work

```
SELECT 
   dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR AS [EHP Code], 
   dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_NA AS [Course Title], 
   LTRIM(RTRIM(FCT_TYP_CD)& ') AND (' & LTRIM(RTRIM(DEP_TYP_ID) & ')' AS [Course Owner]
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Provide examples of what you are getting and what you're expecting

Comment: What's the error you are getting?  and what flavor of SQL? MSFT, Oracle, DB2, MySQL other?

Comment: I am getting an unable to parse query text error its in SQL Server

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You are missing two closing parentheses...and I am not sure an ampersand works as a string concatenation operator.  Try '+'

```
SELECT dbo.COL_V_Cost_GEMS_Detail.TNG_SYS_NR AS [EHP Code], 
dbo.COL_TBL_VCOURSE.TNG_NA AS [Course Title], 
LTRIM(RTRIM(FCT_TYP_CD)) + ') AND (' + LTRIM(RTRIM(DEP_TYP_ID)) + ')' AS [Course Owner]
```

Comment: Ampersand is the [bitwise AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx) operator in SQL Server.

Answer (score 9):

`TRIM` all `SPACE`'s `TAB`'s and `ENTER`'s:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '      
          [         Foo    ]       
          '

DECLARE @NewStr VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @WhiteChars VARCHAR(4) =
      CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- ENTER
    + CHAR(9) -- TAB
    + ' ' -- SPACE

;WITH Split(Chr, Pos) AS (
    SELECT
          SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, 1) AS Chr
        , 1 AS Pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          SUBSTRING(@Str, Pos, 1) AS Chr
        , Pos + 1 AS Pos
    FROM Split
    WHERE Pos <= LEN(@Str)
)
SELECT @NewStr = @NewStr + Chr
FROM Split
WHERE
    Pos >= (
        SELECT MIN(Pos)
        FROM Split
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
    )
    AND Pos <= (
        SELECT MAX(Pos)
        FROM Split
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
    )

SELECT '"' + @NewStr + '"'
```

## As Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION StrTrim(@Str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewStr VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

    IF (@Str IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
        SET @NewStr = ''

        DECLARE @WhiteChars VARCHAR(4) =
              CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- ENTER
            + CHAR(9) -- TAB
            + ' ' -- SPACE

        IF (@Str LIKE ('%[' + @WhiteChars + ']%')) BEGIN

            ;WITH Split(Chr, Pos) AS (
                SELECT
                      SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, 1) AS Chr
                    , 1 AS Pos
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                      SUBSTRING(@Str, Pos, 1) AS Chr
                    , Pos + 1 AS Pos
                FROM Split
                WHERE Pos <= LEN(@Str)
            )
            SELECT @NewStr = @NewStr + Chr
            FROM Split
            WHERE
                Pos >= (
                    SELECT MIN(Pos)
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
                )
                AND Pos <= (
                    SELECT MAX(Pos)
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
                )
        END
    END

    RETURN @NewStr
END
```

#### Example

```
-- Test
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '      
          [         Foo    ]       
              '

SELECT 'Str', '"' + dbo.StrTrim(@Str) + '"'
UNION SELECT 'EMPTY', '"' + dbo.StrTrim('') + '"'
UNION SELECT 'EMTPY', '"' + dbo.StrTrim('      ') + '"'
UNION SELECT 'NULL', '"' + dbo.StrTrim(NULL) + '"'
```

**Result**

```
+-------+----------------+
| Test  | Result         |
+-------+----------------+
| EMPTY | ""             |
| EMTPY | ""             |
| NULL  | NULL           |
| Str   | "[   Foo    ]" |
+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: This replaces all embedded tabs, cr, and lf. Trim usually just removes leading and trailing.

Answer (score 3):

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(FCT_TYP_CD)) & ') AND (' & LTRIM(RTRIM(DEP_TYP_ID)) & ')'
```

I think you're missing a `)` on both of the trims.  Some SQL versions support just TRIM which does both L and R trims...

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
            foo   bar
        Foo           Bar        

'

PRINT '[' + @Str + ']'

DECLARE @StrPrv NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

WHILE ((@StrPrv <> @Str) AND (@Str IS NOT NULL)) BEGIN
    SET @StrPrv = @Str

    -- Beginning
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE @Str LIKE '[' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) + ']%')
        SET @Str = LTRIM(RIGHT(@Str, LEN(@Str) - 1))

    -- Ending
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE @Str LIKE '%[' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(9) + ']')
        SET @Str = RTRIM(LEFT(@Str, LEN(@Str) - 1))
END

PRINT '[' + @Str + ']'
```

Result

```
[
            foo   bar
        Foo           Bar        

]
[foo   bar
        Foo           Bar]
```

## Using fnTrim

Source: https://github.com/reduardo7/fnTrim

```
SELECT dbo.fnTrim(colName)
```