# SQL Server - RTRIM(LTRIM(column)) does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I am constantly selecting columns from a table after trimming them like the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(LTRIM([UN_DataIN])) FROM [Names]
```

This is returning the name `Fadi`

```
SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(LTRIM([UN_DataIN])), LEN(RTRIM(LTRIM([UN_DataIN]))) FROM [Names]
```

when I select the length of the trimmed column, I get back 10.

Which means `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` are not doing their jobs.

Is there an alternative to them?

Comment: How are you selecting the length of the trimmed field?

Comment: @HelpASisterOut Could you give the data on which you are applying rtrim and ltrim

Comment: @AlexK. I edited it please check now.

Comment: Show `cast([UN_DataIN] as varbinary)` to reveal line feeds/tabs etc

Comment: @Alexk 0x45062706470631062920292029202920292029202000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UN_DataIN == 0x45062706470631062920292029202920292029202000

So presuming Arabic your string ends with Unicode paragraph separators *U+2029* and then a single whitespace all of which you need to remove;

```
select rtrim(replace(UN_DataIN, nchar(0x2029), '')) + '!'
```

## ماهر!

Answer (score 3):

This is may work for you as my problem too.. ^-^

```
select rtrim(ltrim(replace(replace(replace(colname,char(9),' '),char(10),' '),char(13),' ')))
from yourtable
```

source : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic288843-8-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you have some new lines in your field text. `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` do not handle those very well.

Comment: I think this is the case. Any suggestion on how to trim those?

Comment: Depending on how much data you have and if it is occurring in all instances you can manually fix (not fun). Or you can convert to ASCII, and replace the ASCII code for new line `CHAR(13)` or `CHAR(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create Function that provide your desired output like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM(@string VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
   RETURN LTRIM(RTRIM(Regex_Replace(@string,'\n','')));
END
GO
```

Here, we are using `regex_replace` to remove if any `New Lines` detected, after that it will apply `RTRIM` and `LTRIM`

Now you can Call this TRIM function in query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dbo.TRIM([UN_DataIN]) FROM [Names];
```

Comment: This works for me +1, just removed Regex_Replace and used built in Replace

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM` all `SPACE`'s `TAB`'s and `ENTER`'s:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '      
          [         Foo    ]       
          '

DECLARE @NewStr VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @WhiteChars VARCHAR(4) =
      CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- ENTER
    + CHAR(9) -- TAB
    + ' ' -- SPACE

;WITH Split(Chr, Pos) AS (
    SELECT
          SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, 1) AS Chr
        , 1 AS Pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          SUBSTRING(@Str, Pos, 1) AS Chr
        , Pos + 1 AS Pos
    FROM Split
    WHERE Pos <= LEN(@Str)
)
SELECT @NewStr = @NewStr + Chr
FROM Split
WHERE
    Pos >= (
        SELECT MIN(Pos)
        FROM Split
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
    )
    AND Pos <= (
        SELECT MAX(Pos)
        FROM Split
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
    )

SELECT '"' + @NewStr + '"'
```

## As Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION StrTrim(@Str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewStr VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

    IF (@Str IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
        SET @NewStr = ''

        DECLARE @WhiteChars VARCHAR(4) =
              CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- ENTER
            + CHAR(9) -- TAB
            + ' ' -- SPACE

        IF (@Str LIKE ('%[' + @WhiteChars + ']%')) BEGIN

            ;WITH Split(Chr, Pos) AS (
                SELECT
                      SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, 1) AS Chr
                    , 1 AS Pos
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                      SUBSTRING(@Str, Pos, 1) AS Chr
                    , Pos + 1 AS Pos
                FROM Split
                WHERE Pos <= LEN(@Str)
            )
            SELECT @NewStr = @NewStr + Chr
            FROM Split
            WHERE
                Pos >= (
                    SELECT MIN(Pos)
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
                )
                AND Pos <= (
                    SELECT MAX(Pos)
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
                )
        END
    END

    RETURN @NewStr
END
```

#### Example

```
-- Test
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '      
          [         Foo    ]       
              '

SELECT 'Str', '"' + dbo.StrTrim(@Str) + '"'
UNION SELECT 'EMPTY', '"' + dbo.StrTrim('') + '"'
UNION SELECT 'EMTPY', '"' + dbo.StrTrim('      ') + '"'
UNION SELECT 'NULL', '"' + dbo.StrTrim(NULL) + '"'
```

**Result**

```
+-------+----------------+
| Test  | Result         |
+-------+----------------+
| EMPTY | ""             |
| EMTPY | ""             |
| NULL  | NULL           |
| Str   | "[   Foo    ]" |
+-------+----------------+
```

*Source*: [How to use a TRIM function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447350/how-to-use-a-trim-function-in-sql-server/26675574#26675574)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround if you have one space at the end:

```
update tableName set PayeeName = PayeeName + '_Serengeti' where right(PayeeName,1) = ' '
update tableName set PayeeName = Replace(PayeeName,' _Serengeti','') where PayeeName like '%_Serengeti%'
```

If you have many spaces, yo may need to execute the statements until the spaces are all removed.