# SQL Server RTRIM(LTRIM([City])) not stripping whitespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, special-characters, whitespace, trim

After troubleshooting a sproc I realized the fields have an extra character, blank I assume or some special character not visible. For example, the city field contains the value 'Abbeville ' with a length (LEN([city]) of 10. I thought I could trim the white-space with the following:

```
  UPDATE US_City_State
  SET [City] = RTRIM(LTRIM([City]))
```

That didn't work. I cast to varbinary but I don't know what to do from here. The column is defined as a nvarchar. Here's the cast value.

```
  0x4100620062006500760069006C006C006500A000
```

[Update] sample data

```
  City          City_Hex_Value
  Aaronsburg    0x4100610072006F006E0073006200750072006700A000
  Abbeville     0x4100620062006500760069006C006C006500A000
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Len` function returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**. so length will be same `before` and `after` trimming

Comment: Yes, so after the update, the length of the field should be 9 but it's still 10 @NoDisplayName

Comment: can show some sample data

Comment: Can trim with another collation fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe the whitespace is not just a space:

Try this:

```
  UPDATE US_City_State
  SET [City] = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([City], CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(160), '')))
```

---

**Explanation:**
Some white space are not really space (' '). Here are some of the whitespace:

```
CHAR(9)     =   Horizontal Tab
CHAR(10)    =   Line Feed
CHAR(13)    =   Carriage Return
CHAR(160)   =   Non-Breaking Space
```

What I did is remove the above whitespaces. You can replace it by space(' ') or `CHAR(32)`, depends on how you want to handle them.

Comment: @WillLopez Glad I could help. Note that not all whitespace characters are included.

Comment: @wewesthemenace Can you please demonstrate, I didn't get why you have used replace

Comment: Thanks @wewesthemenace, noted. But the ones I needed were :-)

Answer (score 0):

`TRIM` all `SPACE`'s `TAB`'s and `ENTER`'s:

```
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '      
          [         Foo    ]       
          '

DECLARE @NewStr VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @WhiteChars VARCHAR(4) =
      CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- ENTER
    + CHAR(9) -- TAB
    + ' ' -- SPACE

;WITH Split(Chr, Pos) AS (
    SELECT
          SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, 1) AS Chr
        , 1 AS Pos
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
          SUBSTRING(@Str, Pos, 1) AS Chr
        , Pos + 1 AS Pos
    FROM Split
    WHERE Pos <= LEN(@Str)
)
SELECT @NewStr = @NewStr + Chr
FROM Split
WHERE
    Pos >= (
        SELECT MIN(Pos)
        FROM Split
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
    )
    AND Pos <= (
        SELECT MAX(Pos)
        FROM Split
        WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
    )

SELECT '"' + @NewStr + '"'
```

## As Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION StrTrim(@Str VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewStr VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

    IF (@Str IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
        SET @NewStr = ''

        DECLARE @WhiteChars VARCHAR(4) =
              CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) -- ENTER
            + CHAR(9) -- TAB
            + ' ' -- SPACE

        IF (@Str LIKE ('%[' + @WhiteChars + ']%')) BEGIN

            ;WITH Split(Chr, Pos) AS (
                SELECT
                      SUBSTRING(@Str, 1, 1) AS Chr
                    , 1 AS Pos
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                      SUBSTRING(@Str, Pos, 1) AS Chr
                    , Pos + 1 AS Pos
                FROM Split
                WHERE Pos <= LEN(@Str)
            )
            SELECT @NewStr = @NewStr + Chr
            FROM Split
            WHERE
                Pos >= (
                    SELECT MIN(Pos)
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
                )
                AND Pos <= (
                    SELECT MAX(Pos)
                    FROM Split
                    WHERE CHARINDEX(Chr, @WhiteChars) = 0
                )
        END
    END

    RETURN @NewStr
END
```

#### Example

```
-- Test
DECLARE @Str VARCHAR(MAX) = '      
          [         Foo    ]       
              '

SELECT 'Str', '"' + dbo.StrTrim(@Str) + '"'
UNION SELECT 'EMPTY', '"' + dbo.StrTrim('') + '"'
UNION SELECT 'EMTPY', '"' + dbo.StrTrim('      ') + '"'
UNION SELECT 'NULL', '"' + dbo.StrTrim(NULL) + '"'
```

**Result**

```
+-------+----------------+
| Test  | Result         |
+-------+----------------+
| EMPTY | ""             |
| EMTPY | ""             |
| NULL  | NULL           |
| Str   | "[   Foo    ]" |
+-------+----------------+
```

*Source*: [How to use a TRIM function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447350/how-to-use-a-trim-function-in-sql-server/26675574#26675574)